# MinIO Object Storage access via mc command line client

Tags: minio

How to access MinIO Object Storage hosted on public IP, [For example, http://50.60.70.20/ on port 80], using MinIO mc client given that the MinIO Object Storage Console can be accessed via browser. The question is about accessing it via terminal command line using the MinIO mc client.

The following command asks for --api input:

```
% mc alias set myminio http://50.60.70.20/ $ACCESS_KEY $SECRET_KEY
```

Please note that MinIO was deployed to a container with public IP address for evaluation:

```
 docker run \
   -p 9000:9000 \
   -p 9090:9090 \
   --name minio \
   -v ~/minio/data:/data \
   -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER=ROOTNAME" \
   -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=CHANGEME123" \
   quay.io/minio/minio server /data --console-address ":9090
```

Also, the deployment has nothing to do with AWS S3.